# Can we export PDF and PPT of an embedded Power BI report by calling an the Export feature of the Power BI Service/Workspace

Tags: powerbi, export, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

We have an embedded Power BI Report and we wish to have an export functionality in the website which calls the export option that is present in the top bar in the **Power BI Service** and uses those export to **PPT** and **PDF** features. Or maybe similar exports.
OR
Is it possible to enable that Export button from the Power BI Service into the website where the report is embedded?

PS
Looked into [Export Power BI report to file (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to) but looking at the [exportToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group) API page it mentions a Limitation which is that it does not support Premium Per User (PPU) and I am getting **403 Forbidden** response while trying out the API. In our organization we have PPU accounts. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation, `exportToFile` feature is not supported for PRO and PPU user. As of now, there are no other alternatives. Please upgrade your license to use this feature

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to?tabs=gen2