# Can we enable the Export dropdown button from the Power BI Service Navigation strip into an Embedded Report?

Tags: powerbi, export, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

We wish to enable PDF and PPT export functionality in our embedded report for our organization but looking at the API documentations [Export Power BI report to file (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to) and [Reports - Export To File In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group) it seems like it wont for for us as it has a limitation for Premium Per User (PPU) license.

We are now looking for an alternative so that we could enable the Export button from the navigation strip from PBI Service to the website of embedded report. Would be better if we could enable just the export button or hide other buttons in the website.

Comment: No you can't move the export button to the report, the only way is via the PBI Service nav strip or via the embedded export as outlined in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733004/can-we-export-pdf-and-ppt-of-an-embedded-power-bi-report-by-calling-an-the-expor

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.